# MSI DB, Visual Basic and cp1252 encoded string problems

Tags: vba, character-encoding, windows-installer

I have such line of code (generated by MakeMSI)

```
oRec.StringData(2) = "A publicitar a aplicação"
```

oRec is record from Msi database, opened with:

```
oInstaller = MkObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
oMsi = oInstaller.OpenDatabase(MsiName, msiOpenDatabaseModeDirect)
oMsi.OpenView(selectQuery)
```

After executing and commiting string "A publicitar a aplicação" is converted to "A publicitar a aplicaçao" (ã is converted to a) in the database. I'm 100% sure database is cp1252 encoded, as when I edit field manualy and insert ã it displays well. Any ideas how to workaround this?

EDIT:
When building installer on Portugese Windows everything is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the codepage of the computer where you edit the property?

I don't know if VBA uses Unicode internally to store strings or not. If it does, then it should work on any computer; if it does not, then it should work correctly only where the system code page supports ‘ã’.

So another part of the problem is the source file itself: to work as expected it should be Unicode-enabled (UTF-8 or UTF-16), and the interpreter should handle it this was. Otherwise, you'll get unexpected results where the current code page is not compatible with cp1252.

*Check the setting for **Language for non-Unicode programs** in the Regional settings in Windows. It should be set to Portuguese.*

Comment: Thanks that helped. Do you have any idea, how to build automaticly installers for two encodings? i.e. I want to make polish (cp1250) installer and portugese (cp1252) at once. Is there any way to disable vba "string" checking, and just treat it as bytes? Is there any way to prevent this conversion?

Comment: @Kamil I don't know how to make VBA use Unicode strings, I don't even know if it really supports it. Though, you can try saving your scripts in UTF-8 encoding so that the strings would be in Unicode, and it should work correctly: MSI would convert them correctly.